# Bigwedge with multiple lines

Tags: equations, two-column

I have a long equation, which I am trying to fit in a column.
I use a big wedge and I am trying to fit it in multiple lines. When I go for a new line, the alignment is not proper. You can see the small wedge in between two big wedges on the next line. Ideally how I would like is to fit like this -

```
                    line 1
 bigwedge bigwedge    ^
                    line 2
```

I tried with align environment, but it doesn't give me the required alignment.
The code showing the equation is -

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \bigwedge_{\substack{\hat{e}=(v,v') \\ \in E_{\Delta Z}^M}} \bigwedge_{0 \le h < c(v)}
   s({I_{wr}}_{\,h}(\hat{e}))  + I = s({G_{wr}}_{\,h}(\hat{e}))) %\\ 
       \wedge~ \mu({I_{wr}}_{\,h}(\hat{e}))) = \mu({G_{wr}}_{\,h}(\hat{e}))) \\
       \bigwedge_{\hat{e}=(v,v') \in E_{\Delta Z}^M} ~~ \bigwedge_{0 \le h' < c(v')}
   s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))  + I = s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))) \\
        \wedge~ \mu({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))) = \mu({G_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))) 
\end{gather*}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

something close -

```
\begin{spreadlines}{-0.5em}% tweak
\begin{align*}
   & s({I_{wr}}_{\,h}(\hat{e}))  + I = s({G_{wr}}_{\,h}(\hat{e}))) \\
  \bigwedge_{\substack{\hat{e}=(v,v') \\ \in E_{\Delta Z}^M}} \bigwedge_{0 \le h < c(v)} & \phantom{invisible text} \wedge \\ 
  & \mu({I_{wr}}_{\,h}(\hat{e}))) = \mu({G_{wr}}_{\,h}(\hat{e}))) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
       \bigwedge_{\hat{e}=(v,v') \in E_{\Delta Z}^M} ~~ \bigwedge_{0 \le h' < c(v')}
   s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))  + I = s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))) \\
        \wedge~ \mu({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))) = \mu({G_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))) 
\end{align*}
\end{spreadlines}
```

By the way I am using IEEE two-column format.

Thank you !

Comment: You want a nested `gathered` environment for the "line 1 ^ line 2" bit.

Comment: but you might also find it easier to move the definition of the limits outside into the text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt using `gathered` and moving the information about the limits to the text.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
       \bigwedge_{\hat{e}}
       \,
       \bigwedge_{h'}
       \;
       \begin{gathered} 
        s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))  + I = s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))) \\
         {}\wedge{}\\
         \mu({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e})))   = \mu({G_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e})))\\
         \end{gathered}
\end{gather*}
where $\hat{e}=(v,v')\in E^M_{\Delta Z}$ and $0\le h'< c(v')$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to align the equals signs and the little wedge you can use an `aligned` environment instead of the `gathered`, but since the expressions are not very symmetrical the result might look a bit lop-sided.  I've also shown a slightly tigher spacing here, and corrected the extra trailing `)`s from the original.
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
       \bigwedge_{\hat{e}}
       \,
       \bigwedge_{h'}
       \;
       \begin{aligned} 
           s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))  + I &= s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e}))) \\[-2pt]
                                            &\mkern2mu\wedge{}\\[-6pt]
           \mu({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e})))   &= \mu({G_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e})))\\
         \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
where $\hat{e}=(v,v')\in E^M_{\Delta Z}$ and $0\le h'< c(v')$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can align the two subscripts by using `\bigwedge_{\vphantom{h'}\hat{e}}` in the first one.

Comment: is it possible to reduce the space between the three lines? maybe by using `spreadlines`?

Comment: you can put some negative skip at the line ends of the `gathered`.  eg `\\[-3pt]`

Comment: or you could rewrite it using a primitive `halign` and fiddle with the `interlineskip`.

Comment: @egreg the misalignment of the subscripts appears to have been an artefact of my converting to png at 120 pixels. The new png has a higher resolution and the subscripts look aligned properly without any `vphantom`s.

Comment: also the two equal, small wedge are not aligned. is it possible to align them?

Comment: @Thruston You can use `aligned` instead of `gathered` in order to align the equals signs and the small wedge

Comment: @egreg yes I tried that first but it looked lop-sided, so I thought `gathered` looked better.

Comment: @Raj, I also note your original has some extra )s ...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but shouldn't $`rd` and `h'` be aligned?

Answer (score 1):

I propose my improvements to the previous solution. It uses `empheq` in place of `amsmath` with the `overload` options. I manage to have (small) `\ wedge` aligned with the `=` signs, `rd` and `h'` subscripts aligned (no idea why these were different subscripts) and a reduced space between lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

    \begin{gather*}[left =\displaystyle\bigwedge_{\hat{e}}\, \bigwedge_{h'}\enspace ]%
        \begin{aligned}
                s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e})) + I & = s({I_{rd}}_{\,h'}(\hat{e})) \\[-4pt]
                   & {\ \wedge}\\[-4pt]
         \mu(I_{rd\:h'}(\hat{e}))
        & = \mu(G_{rd\:h'}(\hat{e}))
        \end{aligned}
    \end{gather*}
where $\hat{e}=(v,v')\in E^M_{\Delta Z}$ and $0\le h'< c(v')$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you left the first set of subscripts unaligned to show the difference?  I ignored that bit of the OP post.  I thought it was irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Thruston: No it's an error. Thank you for pointing it, I'll change that in a minute. You're right, it's  irrelevant to the question, but I often improve details like that. LaTeX taught me to have high standards for typography;).